# Django: database access

Tags: django

I have a Django project called `myproj`, with an app called `myapp`, containing a model called `Mymodel`. In `myproj/myapp`, I want to create a Python script that accesses the database. I know how to access the database from `myproj/myapp/views.py`, but if I have a blank file at `myproj/myapp/myscript.py`, then what do I need to do to enable database interaction? Currently, if I just write the following in the script:

```
from models import mymodel
objs = Mymodel.objects.all()
```

But I get a load of errors for that. Any help?

Comment: You should read through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/). It will show you like this. And in general, rather than just posting "I get a load of errors", post the actual traceback!

Comment: Yes I have gone through the tutorial, but it only shows how to do database accessing via the Python shell when in the `myproj` directory, or via `views.py` in the `myproj/myapp` directory. I want to create a separate script in the `myproj/myapp` directory and this is not discussed.

Comment: What are you trying to do, and why does it need to be outside the normal `models.py`/`test.py`/`views.py` files for your app?

Comment: Basically I want to take some data from the database, manipulate it a little, and output it to a text or csv file. So it's just something I would call manually myself, nothing to do with a user interacting with the website. Where should this go?

Answer (score -1):

Create a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Comment: Based on OP's comments, this is the correct answer, but I can't +1 you for just a link and no code or explanation.

Comment: now the link is dead, go here e.g.: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/